# How to store and access domain vs view state?

Tags: architecture

I'm currently developing an application using the Dear ImGui library: https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/. And I'm trying to figure out how exactly to access state vs domain data. I'm trying to write it in a purely functional way, using something like:

```
function View1(DomainModel & model) {
    ImGui::Begin("View window");
    ...
    ImGui::End();
}
```

But then I run into the issue of needing local variables, for things like window visibility. So, this becomes:

```
function View1(DomainModel & model, ViewState & state) {
    if (state.windowVisible) {
        ImGui::Begin("View window");
        ...
        ImGui::End();
    }
}
```

But now both `model` and `state` need to managed and stored somewhere (currently using a centralized store). Is this the best way to go? What should I be looking at for the storage of domain vs view state?

Answer (score 1):

**The View Model**

Is the model the view should receive. It should contain all of the data required to render the view.

Of course this might mean several things for the Domain Model:

1. The View Model inherits Domain Model.
2. The View Model has a property storing the Domain Model
3. Another function and family of listeners is responsible for updating the ViewModel based on the state of some DomainModel out there that is completely unknown to the View.